# SQL Search for one value in any column of a table inside a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I have a view for a table to validate the data.

```
CREATE VIEW [VendorView]
AS 
    WITH Vendors AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [VendorCode],[VendorName]), 0) AS RN, * 
        FROM [A0112].[Vendor]
    )
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN [VendorCode] IS NULL OR [VendorCode] ='' 
                THEN 'ERROR'
                ELSE [VendorCode] 
        END AS [VendorCode]
        ,[VendorName]
        ,[VendorCategory]
        ,[Address]
        ,[Region]
        ,[State]
        ,[Province]
        ,[Country]
        ,[Contact]
        ,[VendorStatus]
        ,[VendorRating]
        ,[AuthorizationGroup]
        ,[Currency]
        ,[RecordDateTime]
        ,[ErrorStatus]
    FROM   
        Vendors
    WHERE 
        RN IN (SELECT MAX(RN) MAX_RN
               FROM Vendors 
               GROUP BY 
                   [VendorCode], [VendorName], [VendorCategory],
                   [Address], [Region], [State], [Province],
                   [Country], [Contact], [VendorStatus],
                   [VendorRating], [AuthorizationGroup], [Currency])
```

And in my view you can see I'm checking whether **VendorCode is NULL or empty** and return **ERROR** instead of its value.

There 'll be 1 or more Case statements like this to validate the data of the table.

What I need is I need to add a common error `Invalid Record` to `ErrorStatus` column, if any  column   consist value **Error** .

Because When I use this view, I don't like to have multiple conditions to check error columns in my Where Clause like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM [VendorView]
WHERE VendorCode <> 'ERROR' 
  AND [VendorName] <> 'ERROR'
```

I would like to have..

```
   SELECT * FROM [VendorView]
    WHERE [ErrorStatus]<> 'Invalid Record'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways to do that. First way is to use `case` statement for `ErrorStatus` column as below

```
 CASE WHEN [VendorCode] IS NULL OR [VendorCode] ='' 
           OR [VendorName] IS NULL OR [VendorName] = ''
      THEN 'Invalid Record'  
      ELSE 'Valid Record'
END as ErrorStatus
```

Second way is to use below condition for the view (but I'm not sure if it suits you )

```
SELECT * 
FROM [VendorView]
WHERE 'Invalid Record' in ([VendorCode],[VendorName])
```